# How to write a script to check whether the date format is correct or not

Tags: regex, postman, postman-testcase

Below is the array I got in postman. I have to write a script to check the date format is correct or not.
can anyone please help.

```
[
   {
      "sportName":"cricket",
      "sportId":"1.923",
      "nextSportDateTime":"2023-01-14T12:30:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "sportName":"football",
      "sportId":"1.922",
      "nextSportDateTime":"2023-01-18T12:30:00.000Z"
   },
   {
      "sportName":"table tennis",
      "sportId":"1.924",
      "nextSportDateTime":"2023-01-23T12:30:00.000Z"
   }
]
```

So far I've tried

```
this pm.test('Check the date format', () => {
    _.each(jsonData.body,(item)=>{
    pm.expect(item.nextSportDateTime).to.match(/^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}-\`T`\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{3}$/);
    });
})
```

It didn't work

Comment: What does "didn't work" mean? I surely see an excessive dash before the `T` in the regex. Also, unsure why this would need backticks around the `T`. And the `Z` is missing before the closing `$`. So I guess the regular expression is to blame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This Regex will do it: `^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}\.\d{3}Z$`.
See https://regex101.com/r/MBbe31/1

You missed the `Z` at the end.
Also I'm not sure why you put a dash - before the T and backkticks around it.